# Sort JSON object in iOS

Tags: ios, json

```
“Colors” : {
    “Red : {
            “R” : 255,
            “G” : 100,
            “B” : 190,
            “Light” : {
                “R” : 195,
                “G” : 420,
                “B” : 255,
            },
            “Dark” : {
                “R” : 36.3458,
                “G” : 125.047,
                “B” : 49.4638,
            }
        },
        “Green” : {
            “R” : 12,
            “G” : 232,
            “B” : 150,
            “Light” : {
                “R” : 195,
                “G” : 420,
                “B” : 255,
            },
            “Dark” : {
                “R” : 36.3458,
                “G” : 125.047,
                “B” : 49.4638,
            }
        },
        “Blue” : {
            “R” : 105,
            “G” : 200,
            “B” : 150,
            “Light” : {
                “R” : 195,
                “G” : 420,
                “B” : 255,
            },
            “Dark” : {
                “R” : 36.3458,
                “G” : 125.047,
                “B” : 49.4638,
            }
        },
}
```

I want to sort on "R", "G", "B" in iOS. Sorting on not "Light" RGB and "Dark" RGB.

How do we sort a JSON object ? Please help me with it.

I am able to sort "R", "G", "B". but objects "Red", "Green", "Blue" is not coming in  the right order.

```
NSSortDescriptor * brandDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"R" ascending:YES];
NSArray * sortDescriptor = [NSArray arrayWithObject:brandDescriptor];
```

Output

```
Red        12
Green      105
Blue       255
```

You can see I sorted on "R", and values are in sorting order but color values "Red, green, blue" is not in order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't sort JSON objects. But if the JSON data is loaded into arrays, your can sort the array.

Comment: @rmaddy Exactly. @user3908542 you don't have any arrays in your json object. Only arrays are `ordered collections`, what you have are dictionaries and dictionaries are `unordered collections`, so you just cannot sort them. As rmaddy said you have to store them in an array to sort them.

Comment: @maddy and @HAS: you both are incorrect. The `NSDictionary` is just a _representation_ of a JSON Object. And this kind of container happens to be an _unordered_ associative container, The JSON Object could be very well represented as a `std::map`, which is an _ordered_ associative container and thus can be sorted according its `Compare` function. The JSON itself is just text where "sort" is meaningless. But we can possibly sort its representation, even from a JSON Object if this is a sorted associative container.

Comment: I solved the issue. Now I am having another issue related to this. I am getting below error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key <JSON object Key>" I have space in the object name, It is working nice without space in object name but if there is space for object name then it gives me error. Example : Object name "BrandName" then working, Object name "Brand Name", start giving me error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Brand Name."

Comment: First off, go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax, at least well enough so that you don't omit critical characters when you copy/paste an example.

Comment: @HotLicks I can't put my actual JSON object. I just need idea about my question. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

What others are saying in the comments is correct, but from what I am seeing in your question you do not need to sort really. If I understand correctly, you are simply looking to get the value for "R" in the "Red," "Green," and "Blue" dictionaries that are in the JSON. One way to do this is the following:

```
// grab json object here, which in your case returns a dictionary 
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:data // where data is simply your json above, for example
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
NSDictionary *colors = [json valueForKey:@"Colors"]; // gives you a handle on the whole json blob of Colors
NSLog(@"R: %@", [[colors valueForKey:@"Red"] valueForKey:@"R"]); // this gets the R value for Red
NSLog(@"G: %@", [[colors valueForKey:@"Green"] valueForKey:@"R"]); // this gets the R value for Green
NSLog(@"B: %@" [[colors valueForKey:@"Blue" valueForKey:@"R"]); // this gets the R value for Blue
```

Does that help?

(Also, you may need to use better format specifiers for the R values, depending on how they are returned. If integers use %d, if float/double use %f)

Comment: I solved the issue. I can't put my actual JSON object. Now I am having another issue related to this. I am getting below error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key <JSON object Key>" I have space in the object name, It is working nice without space in object name but if there is space for object name then it gives me error. Example : Object name "BrandName" then working, Object name "Brand Name", start giving me error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Brand Name." Any help on this ?